# HTML DOM PARSER UTF-8

Tags: php, html, utf-8, domparser

i have a website but not encoded with UTF-8. And i am including php file in another php. When i change encoding to UTF-8 all the characters went broken. So i can't use header(..utf8 bla bla tag.

```
include_once 'includes/simple_html_dom.php';

$ozet = file_get_contents($url);
$html = str_get_html($ozet);
$trozet = $html->find('div[class="TEST"]',0)->plaintext;
$icerik = "";
$yazi = "<span>$trozet</span>";
$uzunluk = strlen($yazi);
$sinir = 155;
if ($uzunluk > $sinir) {
$icerik = substr($yazi,0,$sinir) . "...";
}

$content.= '<i><span>'.$icerik.'</span></i>';

return $content;
```

But its getting html like this:

```
Pittsburgh kentinde sakin ve gÃ¼neÅŸli bir sabah, mesai saatinden hemen Ã¶nce insanlar iÅŸlerine doÄŸru koÅŸturmakta, gÃ¼nlÃ¼k telaÅŸlarÄ±nÄ± yaÅŸama...
```

It should be:

```
Pittsburgh kentinde sakin ve güneşli bir sabah, mesai saatinden hemen önce insanlar işlerine doğru koşturmakta, günlük telaşlarını...
```

How can i make this right?

Answer (score 0):

to Substr utf-8 strings you can use a function like this:

```
function substrutf8($str,$from,$len){
return preg_replace('#^(?:[\x00-\x7F]|[\xC0-\xFF][\x80-\xBF]+){0,'. $from .'}'.'((?:[\x00-\x7F]|[\xC0-\xFF][\x80-\xBF]+){0,'. $len .'}).*#s','$1', $str);}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use UTF-8, you must convert it to some other encoding:

```
$yazi = mb_convert_encoding("<span>$trozet</span>", "Windows-1250", "UTF-8");
```

Note that not every website will be in UTF-8 and Windows-1250 supports only a tiny subset of Unicode characters anyway.